# find the sum of the series with given first two terms.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

We are given $2$ integers, $a,b$ such that $0\leq\,a$ and $b\leq9)$, that are the first $2$ elements of a series. Each consecutive term of the series is defined as the sum of all the previous elements of the series, modulo $10$. That is, the first element is $a$, the second element is $b$, the third element (let's call it $c$) is $(a+b)\%10$, the fourth element is $(a+b+c)\%10$, where $c= (a+b)\%10$, and so on. If the series contains $n$ elements, how do I find the sum of the series?
One way to do this is just calculate every term and find the sum, 
but in my case $n$ could be very large, so I need something better than this.

After some calculation , I found that for any given $a$ and $b$,
3rd element $= (1*(a+b))\%10$
4th element $=  (2*(a+b))\%10$
5th element $=  (4*(a+b))\%10$, and so on, but I'm still not able to generate a formula for the sum for the first $n$ terms.

Comment: @416E64726577 sir, i think when any element becomes 0 we will stop and if it becomes 2 , then we can stop as if we got 2 , the pattern will be continued with 2,4,8,6,2,4,8,6,2,4.. and so on, so we can calculate the sum fastly, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: As you mentioned, you're trying to calculate $a + b + \sum_{k=0}^n(2^k (a+b))\% 10$. As modulo doesn't generally distribute, I don't see any obvious closed form$-$but perhaps there is one!

Comment: please tell me more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, let

$$c = (a+b)\%10 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Next, let $f_i$, for $i \ge 1$, be the elements of the series, so $f_1 = a$, $f_2 = b$, $f_3 = c$ and, in general, for $i \ge 3$, you get

$$f_i = \left(2^{i-3}c\right)\%10 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Next, note that $2^{5+j} = 32 \times 2^j \equiv 2 \times 2^j \equiv 2^{j+1} \pmod{10}$ for $j \ge 0$. Thus, this shows the values in \eqref{eq2} start repeating, with a period of $4$, beginning at $i = 4$. You can therefore determine the sum $S_n$ based on the value of $n$ being less than $4$ (i.e., $S_1 = a$, $S_2 = a + b$, $S_3 = a + b + c$), else its value based on its quotient and remainder modulo $4$.

Comment: whenever i got 2 or 0 i stopped further process, if i got 0 i returned the current sum , if i got 2 then i know that it will now repeat as 2 4 8 6 , thus solved thanks.

Comment: @AdityaRoshan You're welcome. This shows that you sometimes you need to check a bit further to see if there's any particular pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Note:  this assumed that the whole sum was to be reduced $\bmod 10$.  It appears not, but I will leave it anyway.

The whole system is linear, so we can compute the values starting with $1,0$ and $0,1
$.  If we ignore the mod $10$ we get
$$1,0,1,2,4,8,16,\ldots 2^{n-3}\\
0,1,1,2,4,8,16,\ldots,2^{n-3}$$
Now we can multiply the first by $a$, the second by $b$, add them, and take the result $\bmod 10$.  For $n \ge 3$ the result is
$$(a+b)2^{n-3} \bmod 10$$
Now if we add these up, because there were two $1$s at the start we just get
$$(a+b)2^{n-2} \bmod 10$$

Comment: sir, but this will help me in getting the nth term , how can i get the sum from this ?

Comment: @RossMillikan Using $a = 3$ and $b = 8$, for just $n = 2$, the sum is $11$ but your answer gives $1$ instead. When adding the values $\%10$, i.e., between $0$ and $9$, you can't instead just add the original values and then take the result modulo $10$. Note the OP wants the actual sum of the terms, not what they are modulo $10$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan:  I had missed that.  I thought the whole sum was to be reduced $\bmod 10$.  It is much easier that way.